# What's wrong with my C# code?

Tags: c#, for-loop, error-handling

```
string num = Console.ReadLine();

string a="";
string b="";
for (int i = num.Length; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (num[i] =='-')
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        b +=num[i].ToString();
    }
}

//then reverse b 
//a=num-(b.lenght+1);
Console.WriteLine(b);``
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in number_spliter.exe
>
> Additional information:
>
> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: i don't know whats wrong with it?

Comment: i think you need to explain what you would like to achieve and what error did you get

Answer (score 2):

Arrays start at index zero

```
for (int i = num.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```